# How to create while loop checking for input

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I know this is simple, but for some reason I can't figure out how to create a while loop checking for inputs. Basically, how do i create a loop that asks for a value and if the value is less than whats required keep looping until it gets that value. For example My program requires a number greater than or equal to 7 but if a 6 is entered, It keeps prompting the user to enter the required value?

```
width = int(raw_input("How Long?"))

if width >= 7:
        width = input()
else:
    print('Has to be less than 7')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
width = int(raw_input("How Long?"))

while width <= 7:
    print "Min 7"
    width = int(raw_input())
```

Comment: Yeah perfect thanks. For some reason I couldn't think of it.